# Gradle: How to designate a output directory for C/C++ object files?

Tags: c, gradle, native

I have a fairly simple build.gradle file which builds a zlib directory.  Unfortunately, the resulting *.o file are sprinkled into individual directories.  
e.g.

```
build/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/xvtb7xzcn488esep2yp1v714/uncompr.o
build/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/2osjpf8p443huii37rw8g7o7d/zutil.o
[...]
build/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/bkho3m4h5simvpsegapx51g54/trees.o
build/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/2zicemubjlmw82yi1ysriaup4/inflate.o
```

How do you set the output directory to be **build/zlib** for all the resulting *.o files (minus the unique-id directories)?

```
apply plugin: 'c'

FileCollection zlibfiles = files(
            'adler32',
            [...]
            'trees',
            'zutil')

model {
    components {
        zlib(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                c {
                    source {
                        srcDir "."
                        include '*.c'
                    }
                    exportedHeaders {
                        srcDir '.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    binaries {
        withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) {
            if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.linux) {
                cppCompiler.args '-c', '-g', '-fPIC'
                // relative paths are ignored by Gradle
                // only fully qualified paths are recognized 
                // cppCompiler.args '-I', '../..'
                cppCompiler.args '-I', "${rootDir}/zlib"
                linker.args '-pthread'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a find-copy task, but the goal here is use Gradle properly.  I would rather use Gradle's version of gcc/g++ '-o' option.

```
task zlibcopy (type: Copy) {
    configurations {
        conf
    }
    dependencies {
        conf fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/")
    }
    from configurations.conf.getAsFileTree()
    into "${rootDir}/build/client/ps/common/zlib"
}
```

Gradle: 4.7
CentOS: 7.4
Java: 1.8.0_144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Gradle does not allow native code to be outputted to a designated output directory.  You can find the *.o's in uniquely identified output directories, the *.so in a "shared" directory, and *.a in a "static" directory.  Darn.

Comment: Not a big deal, postprocess the files after that. Gradle is designed for that.

Comment: I would heartily disagree on the point that it is "not a big deal."  If you would like to debate this point, please contact me via the chat instead of commenting on the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try that, the unique directories won't be included.

```
task zlibcopy (type: Copy) {
    zlibfiles.each { File file ->
        println file.name
        from ("${buildDir}/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/") {
            include "**/${file.name}*"
        }
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        eachFile {
            def (id, name) = it.path.split('/')
            it.relativePath = RelativePath.parse(true, name)
        }
        into "${rootDir}/build/zlib"
    }
}
```

> the last six *.o files are never copied

Maybe these six files are not included in `zlibfiles` and by consequence, never included ?

Comment: I did check.  The filenames are listed in the zlibfiles list.

Comment: and they have a matching file in `"${buildDir}/objs/zlib/shared/zlibC/` ?

Comment: No, your response does not.  The question is, "Gradle: How to designate an output directory for C/C++ object files."   Your response was to do a find-copy which I specifically said in the bounty I do not want. I already have a working find-copy.  I want to use Gradle properly and set the cppCompiler output directory.

Comment: working find-copy ? *I've even tried to do a copy of the .o files, but the unique-id-directory-name was copied too* Moreover Gradle is all about this kind of tricks and customization.

Comment: Correct.  As you have shown, I already have a find-copy.  What I asked for is Gradle's version of gcc/g++ "-o"  option.